# The output produced by octo.exe is wrapped in an annoying way, can it be configured not to?

Tags: octopus-deploy

For example, this is one such output:

[image]

The lines are wrapped and indented. I can only assume that `octo.exe` faithfully outputs what it receives from the Octopus Server.

So, the question is - how can we configure Octopus Server to stop this annoying wrapping and indentation?

Please, note that the Octopus process in question contains a lot of steps and so suggestions to modify all the steps are unacceptable.

I am looking for some kind of a change to be done in a single place, maybe the Powershell `$PROFILE` script or some kind of a configuration in Octopus itself.

Comment: Octo.exe v4.30+ supports JSON formatted output which may help - [JSON Formatted Output](https://octopus.com/docs/api-and-integration/octo.exe-command-line/formatted-output). Also, it is open-source, so you can contribute or fork it too.

Comment: Are you sure octo.exe is at fault? I think this is how Octopus Server sends the output to the client.

Comment: The output formatting is handled by octo.exe in [this method](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusClients/blob/b15544ac60b8b8993743ef2f2c148670824257b4/source/Octopus.Cli/Commands/Deployment/TaskOutputProgressPrinter.cs#L52)